# How to get value of star rating from repeater?

Tags: asp.net

I have an application with star rating.
Star rating inside repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="reptweet" runat="server" onitemcommand="reptweet_ItemCommand">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div class="divtweet"> 
                                        <span class="box_imag">
                                            <asp:Image ID="ScreenImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ImageUrl")%>' height="50" width="50"  /></span>                     
                                        <span class="box_cont">
                                            <div><strong> <a rel="external" href='http://twitter.com/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ScreenName")%>' target="_blank">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblScreenName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ScreenName")%>'></asp:Label></a></strong>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text")%>'></asp:Label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="meta"><asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date")%>'></asp:Label></div>
                                        </span>
                                                                               <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtpnlTweet" runat="server">
                                                <ContentTemplate>
                                                        <cc1:Rating ID="rateTweet" runat="server"             
                                                            CurrentRating="3" 
                                                             MaxRating = "5"
                                                            StarCssClass="ratingStar"
                                                            EmptyStarCssClass="empatyStarRating"
                                                            FilledStarCssClass="filledStarRating" 
                                                            WaitingStarCssClass="savedStarRating"
                                                            OnChanged="rateTweet_Changed"
                                                             >
                                                        </cc1:Rating>
                                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="100px" CssClass="dropdowntweet" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CategoryName" DataValueField="CategoryId"  >
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </div>   
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
```

Through this code its shows multiple rows and i want sort this repeater content on the basis of star rating.

So can i get the value of star according per row.

Or is there any other way for star rating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a setup of repeating values broken up into rows a grid view control might make things much easier.  A repeater isn't really designed for the concept of date being broken up into logical "rows", it's really made so you can customize the format of your repeating data.  Trying to iterate through a repeater is quite a pain in the neck.

With the grid view iterating through your rows is as simple as:

```
    foreach (GridViewRow ratingRow in RatingGrid.Rows)
    {
        Rating ratingControl;
        int rating;

        ratingControl = (Rating)(ratingRow.FindControl("rateTweet"));
        rating = ratingControl.CurrentRating;
    }
```

Good grid view examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479339.aspx)

Comment: @pankaj can u plz tell me, what you did to get current rating from database, what  is the datatype you used to store the ratings? 
i am using CurrentRating='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ratings")%>' but it thrown an error : InvalidCastException